# bootstrap switch d3 on change event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, event-handling, bootstrap-switch

I'm putting together a d3 visualization that makes use of bootstrap and the bootstrap-switch libraries.

I've got a set of switches that are being generated by d3 which I'd like to listen to so that I can update the visualization based on their status; I've got an event listener on the switches but it's not doing anything:

```
d3.selectAll(".input").on("change", function() {
    console.log(this)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jy24dk20/1/

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap switch (**2.0.1**, which is legacy) fires an event called [`switch-change`, as per the docs](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/documentation-2.html).

It appears that it does not change the `checked` state on the input and, hence, does not trigger the `change` event.

I would recommend listening to the `switch-change` event to affect your changes:

```
$('input').bootstrapSwitch().on("switch-change", function() {
    console.log(this)
})
```